# could not use multiple layout when using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The project i am doing needs two layout, one homepage (which is right now app.js) and another result page. When the form is filled and submitted, the results should be shown in another layout(result layout not app). But when i submit the form, the url gets redirected to `/car` but the same app layout is shown.

**Here is my code**

**app.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Nav
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </Nav>
            <Banner>
              { location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname === '/apartamentos' ||
              location.pathname === '/coche' || location.pathname === '/experiencias' ?
               this.props.children : ''
             }
            </Banner>
            <Destinos />
            <Footer />
          </div>
          );
  }
}
```

**result.js**

```
const Result = (children) => <div>{children}</div>;
```

**car-result.js**

```
class CarResult extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Car Result here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**routes.js**

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Apartamentos} />
      <Route path="coche" component={Coche} />
      <Route path="experiencias" component={Experiencias} />
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route component={Result}>
        <Route path="car" component={CarResult} />
      </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are keeping `result` as child of your `app`

Refactor your `routes` like this might work for you

```
export default (
  <Route path="/">
      <Route component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Apartamentos} />
        <Route path="coche" component={Coche} />
        <Route path="experiencias" component={Experiencias} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
      <Route component={Result}>
        <Route path="car" component={CarResult} />
      </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

But my suggestion is to maintain a separate `container` for `Application` which contains `home` and `result` containers as children which are rendered by `routes`. As follows

```
   <Route path="/" component={App}> //App is root Application
      <Route component={Home}> //Home with before login content
        <IndexRoute component={Apartamentos} />
        <Route path="coche" component={Coche} />
        <Route path="experiencias" component={Experiencias} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
      <Route component={Result}> //Result with after login content
        <Route path="car" component={CarResult} />
      </Route>
  </Route>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It worked. Can you show a simple idea(just a layout) of separate container you are recommending about?

Comment: Actually `App.js` is to bootstrap your application. Then routes will load appropriate containers to your `App`. As of now you can go with existing solution. But suggestion is to follow proper design.